# Silverlight OOB App and Web Service in same Solution

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I'm using vs2012 and have created a Silverlight 5 out of browser application that talks to a MVC 4 webapi web service for its data.

With both projects in the same solution I can successfully fire up and test the silverlight application with the web service if I have the web service set as the startup project and have the application running in the browser and embedded in a view on the MVC web service site.  If I set the silverlight application as the startup application so that I can run it out of the browser like the user will, then the MVC site doesn't get started and the web service isn't available to connect to.

Is there anyway to have both projects running in the same instance of visual studio, but have the silverlight app run out of browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Right click on solution from Solutin Explorer and select Properties. Then select the Multiple startup project option inside Common Properties/Startup Project and set both as 'Start'. Close and Start Debug again.

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't even know you could do that. Thanks